# PyQt - Two Menus Produced, One Desired

Tags: python, csv, user-interface, pyqt, analytics

Below is part of a PyQT GUI script in which I am trying to create continent menus within a previously defined country menu. For some reason, though, this script is making two sets of menus; one untitled set and within each untitled part the titled continent (see screenshot below).

[image]

The desired result is to replace the blank menus with the continent menus they contain. I am quite a novice with PyQt so it is likely I have made a simple error in the menu definition but I have been unable to find it.

```
Continents = {}
    DIR = '/Users/jonathan/Documents/CountryWiseAnalytics/'
    with open(DIR + 'UsersPerCountry.csv', 'r') as UPC:
        UsersCountry = csv.DictReader(UPC, restval=None, restkey=None, dialect='excel')
        for row in UsersCountry:
            Continent = row['Continent:']
            if Continent not in Continents:
                self.menuContinent = QtGui.QMenu(self.menuCountry)
                ContinentMenu = Continents.setdefault(Continent, self.menuContinent.addMenu(Continent))
                self.menuCountry.addAction(self.menuContinent.menuAction())
```

**EDIT:**

Following your advice I get this, as described in comment below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the addition of the continent is conditional. The addition of country should happen at each iteration of the loop.
My answer in the previous question was dealing with the consition via the setdefault ;-)

```
continents = {}
DIR = '/Users/jonathan/Documents/CountryWiseAnalytics/'
with open(DIR + 'UsersPerCountry.csv', 'r') as UPC:
    UsersCountry = csv.DictReader(UPC, restval=None, restkey=None, dialect='excel')
    for row in UsersCountry:
        continent = row['Continent:']
        continentMenu = continents.get(continent, None)
        if continentMenu is None:
            continentMenu = self.menuCountry.addMenu(continent))
            continents[continent] = continentMenu
        useless_action = continentMenu.addAction(row['Country:'])
```

Comment: I know the addition of country should happen at each iteration of the for loop, that's not what's at question here. The question is why is there this blank menu set as seen in the screenshot?

Comment: because you redefine menuContinent each iteration, without setting any title to it.

Comment: The purpose of the 'if continent in continents:' line is that there are obviously multiple countries in the database in each continent. When I replace with your code I simply get more blank menus corresponding to the continent of every country in the database.

Comment: Sorry, rightmost expression of setdefault evaluated each time. Not lazy evaluation, my bad. Corrected my code.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if you would then know how to assign a function that takes the country as an input to each countryAction within each continent?

Comment: Better use QObject.connect

Comment: Better use useful_action.triggered.connect(lambda: my_receiver(useful_action)) ?